# In chef, how do I update environment attributes from a recipe?

Tags: chef-infra, chef-recipe

I defined environment attributes in an environment file, used to override the default settings in a node. 
In my case, I would like to update an environment attribute in a recipe so when running `chef-client` on `b_node_name` the environment attribute will change from this:

```
default_attributes "hosts" => ["a_node_name"]
```

to this:

```
default_attributes "hosts" => ["a_node_name", "b_node_name"]
```

Doing this I want the new `b_node_name` where I ran `chef-client` added to the array so all nodes will get the updated list for new `chef-client` runs.

Is this possible to do? Should I be using data bags instead to make all nodes read and update that info from there? I'm looking for the best approach to implement this.
I would really apprecciatte much any help.

**UPDATE:** 
I added the following lines to my recipe:

```
Chef::Log.info("---> Before update. hosts=#{node.hosts}")
node.override['hosts'] = ["a_hostname", "b_hostname"] 
Chef::Log.info("---> After update. hosts=#{node.hosts}")
```

And I'm getting this output:

First chef-client run in `b_hostname`:

```
#chef-client --log_level info

[2015-07-29T14:29:13+00:00] INFO: ---> Before update. hosts=["a_hostname"]
[2015-07-29T14:29:13+00:00] INFO: ---> After update. hosts=["a_hostname", "b_hostname"]
```

Second chef-client run in `b_hostname`:

```
#chef-client --log_level info
[2015-07-29T14:30:33+00:00] INFO: ---> Before update. hosts=["a_hostname"]
[2015-07-29T14:30:33+00:00] INFO: ---> After update. hosts=["a_hostname", "b_hostname"]
```

So the hosts value that `b_hostname` reads is `hosts=["a_hostname"]` and I want that to be  `hosts=["a_hostname", "b_hostname"]` for the second run.

If I go through Chef Server UI to the node and check `hosts` attribute I see hosts set to `["a_hostname", "b_hostname"]` instead of `hosts=["a_hostname"]`

Why am I getting `hosts=["a_hostname"]` during `chef-client` run?

**UPDATE 2:**
Using `node.set` instead of `node.default` or `node.override` makes the value to persist but just for the node where I ran chef-client (not all nodes) so the above scenario works but not the following one:

First chef-client run in `c_hostname`:

```
[2015-07-29T14:58:51+00:00] INFO: ---> Before update. hosts=["a_hostname"]
[2015-07-29T14:58:51+00:00] INFO: ---> After update. hosts=["a_hostname", "b_hostname"]
```

Where I want to see hosts array set to ["a_hostname", "b_hostname"] done by chef-client run in `b_hostname`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

UPDATED to allow sorting by time added.

you need to use search.  Rather than use an attribute to determine the list, use an attribute to indicate a given node belongs in the list.

```
node.set['include_me'] = Time.now
```

Then search for all nodes that have set this, sort them, and get their fqdn:

```
sorted = search(:node, 'include_me:*').sort_by { |node| node['include_me'] }
hostnames = sorted.map{ |node| node.fqdn }
```

This will give you an array of fqdns `hostnames` that is sorted by the added date.  One caveat, it will only include nodes that have finished their run.  So if you have nodes building in parallel, they will not see one another.  Furthermore, the current node will not show up on its first run.  So you'll need a little more logic to search for the current node and then add it to the list if it is missing.

Comment: The need to keep a list is because I want to know the sequence order of the nodes that are appended to the list. I'm afraid that doing a search won't tell me nothing about this.

Comment: Updated it to include sorting by time added.  Still has the same caveat as before, but it gets you closer.

Comment: Thank u very much, this solved my question. I was using data bag item so far but this requires to set admin permissions for my client nodes. This alternative is far better. Thanks!

Comment: you probably would want to use `node.set_unless['include_me'] = Time.now` so that once the node is tagged with its time it doesn't update on every chef-client run.

Answer (score 1):

Chef resets the attributes every single run so the behavior you are seeing is intended - check https://docs.chef.io/attributes.html

If you want to persist a node attribute change between runs use the node.set -  in your case

```
node.set['hosts'] = ['a_node_name', 'b_node_name']
```

Be careful when changing node attributes during chef client runs - chef client first compiles the attributes to predetermine node attribute values then runs the recipes so if you want to dynamically change the value during run time you might need to put the node.set in a ruby block

Comment: In this case, the attribute persists but if I run chef-client in a third node 'c_hostname' I'm still seeing the original value set in the environment file which is ["a_hostname"]. How can I make the updated hosts attribute visible for all nodes, on every chef-client run?

Comment: Unfortunately that is not possible, every node has its unique set of attributes that belong to that node, looking closer at your code what you actually want is to set the node['node_name'] value to the name of that node and then if you need the name of other nodes do a search for nodes and get the names of those nodes - check out http://serverfault.com/questions/412127/chef-recipe-read-attributes-from-another-node

Comment: Instead of having each node requesting the name of the other nodes I want each node to update a global hosts array that can be used by the rest of the nodes on each run. That's why I was thinking that maybe data bags is a good fit for this. I thought about using an array because I would like to know the order, so every node after a chef-client run is appended to hosts array.

Comment: Yeah unfortunately I don't think that is possible and is also a limitation I have run into my Chef projects - data bags won't work either as  a data bag can be edited in two ways: using knife or by using the Chef management console - not from a recipe.

Comment: It seems that they can be edited from a recipe: https://docs.chef.io/data_bags.html#load-with-dsl-recipe

Comment: Good to know, that might come in handy

Comment: Yeah but I'm a bit concerned about this time consuming approach. Probably this is the only alternative I have. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

In the recipe, do this to dynamically changing the value of the attribute.

```
node.default['hosts'] = ['a_node_name', 'b_node_name']
```

Comment: This only will update the attribute in the current node. So if I run the same recipe in another node it will get the original list and not the updated one though

Comment: If you add this in your recipe, any node that runs the recipe will have the attribute set to the new array value.

Comment: I can see that the attribute gets updated in the node if I check that through Chef server UI but inside the recipe I still read the original list. Could you check my update in this question, please?